support nvidia GTX 660 TI
'I installed 24.10 (Oracular Oriole).
The required driver for NVIDIA GTX 660 TI (470) has been withdrawn.
nouveau gives frequent problems -> not usable
The proprietary driver from NVIDIA does not install.
Do you intend to reissue nvidia-driver-470 ?
Is there another driver to support that GPU ?
If not, do I have to install a newer GPU ?
If so, is Canonical willing to foot the bill ?
executing ubuntu-drivers install returns 'All the available drivers are already installed'. A reboot doesn't change anything.

What happens if you run the following command: sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot ? This command tells the ubuntu-drivers program to install the proprietary drivers that are recommended for your nvidia GPU automatically.

I am not affiliated with Ubuntu or Canonical but I will try to answer this.
Proprietary drivers from Nvidia are controlled by Nvidia, if they chose to end support for it, there is nothing that Ubuntu can do about that besides offer you the nouveau driver. If you want to file a complaint you should send that to them.
In terms of solutions it would seem that there are two that don't require making hardware changes: Do some troubleshooting with the Nouveau driver and figure out if you can fix the issues you are having or downgrade your Ubuntu back to the last version that does support the driver you need.

The driver 470 is still supported by nvidia but gives errors when installing in Ubuntu 24.10.
The corresponding driver delivered by Ubuntu has been canceled.

Did you try looking for that version of the NVIDIA driver in the official NVIDIA website?
